# Use .data() function to iterate over every nth data member

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code

```
var dataArray = [100, 200, 300, 350, 150];

g.selectAll("bar")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
        .attr("height", function(d) {return height - yScale(d[1]);})
        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth());
```

I want the `data` function to iterate over each alternate value in `dataArray`, not each value in `dataArray`. Is that possible without creating a deep copy of `dataArray` with only the required elements? 
To make the question more generic, is it possible to iterate over each nth member of dataArray.

Comment: `.data()` is used for data binding and it will bind the entire array provided to it. Obviously, there are some iterations performed under the hood, it is not the right tool to iterate yourself, though. Furthermore, doing explicit iterations is not the idiomatic way to use D3. The question seems to be either unfortunately phrased or an XY-problem. So, the short anser is: *no, you can't*. To get help with your actual issue please describe your problem instead of what you think might be the solution.

Comment: @altocumulus  col[0], col[2] & col[4] are Height and col[1], col[3] & col[5] are Weight. I want a bar chart of only Height. If I use `data` function, it will also create rectangles of Weight columns. So I want it to skip the alternate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the [filter()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter) method of a d3 Selection.

```
g.selectAll("bar")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .filter((d,i) => i % 2 == 0)
    ...
```

(DISCLAIMER: I haven't tested it)

However, my recommendation is that you change your data structures to better align with the visualization that you want. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: Thanks. filter() was exactly what I was looking for.